# Manual line break in beamer \title adds spurious comma in \inserttitle

Tags: beamer, line-breaking, titles

Currently I'm preparing a presentation with the beamer class.
I want to add a manual line break (with `\\`) to the title to make it look nicer. However, in the `\inserttitle` command (which I use in the footer), the line break adds a spurious comma.

Is this a bug or a feature? How do I get rid of the comma?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that this is an intended feature of `beamer` (you don't want a line break in the footer anyways, do you?). Well, have you tried this?

```
\title[My long presentation title]{My long \\ presentation title}
```

Of course, you need to use `\insertshorttitle` instead of `\inserttitle`.